# Error "Comparison method violates its general contract!" when installing any Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse

(*I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919916/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-when-trying-to-install-eclips), but that answer doesn't solve my problem, so don't mark this one as duplicate*)

I have a fresh installation of Eclipse (`Eclipse for PHP Developers / Helios Release / Build id: 20100617-1415 on Windows 7 x86`) I can't install any plugin or addition. Neither from official plugins repository, nor from user-provided URLs.

Installation, even of tiny plugins takes "years" (starting at 10-20 minutes, ending on over an hour) though I'm on quite very fast Internet connection (around 2 MB/s), which is strange itself. And it always ends up with the same error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.php, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!
Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

Error message is always the same, always mentioning `epp.package.php`, no matter, what plugin I'm trying to install. So I assume, that this is Eclipse-related, not plugin-related problem.

I did some reasearch on StackExchange (many similar topics but clearly programming question, related to errors in Java or Javascript code) and in the Internet in genereal. The only thing directly related to Eclipse, that I found was [this forum topic](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/243191/731157/#msg_731157) saying about some [know bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/317785). Though this bug is marked as `resolved fixed`, I tried to adapt one of proposed quick solutions of starting Eclipse with:

```
eclipse.exe -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

(*other, similar sources are unclear, whether there should be a space between `-D` and `java.*` or not*)

But this has brought no effect. Again, installing even small plugin even from official repository takes very, very wrong and upon progress bar reaching around 20% (after about 20-30 minutes) entire installation process ends up with above error.

I have newest available stable versions of Eclipse for PHP and JRE.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919916/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-when-trying-to-install-eclips), but it brought me no closer to the solution. I saw no difference, when starting Eclipse with `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` switch and I wasn't able to update core Eclipse to newest version, because this process also failed with the same error.

And this does not explains, why installing anything takes so incredibly long on fairly fast connection?

Is downgrading to JRE 6 the only option I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` must come after the `-vmargs` switch, as that changes the command line from specifying Eclipse launch arguments to arguments to the JVM, which any `-D` would be.

Use this solution or upgrade to at least `Indigo SR2`.

Comment: I can't use `Indigo` as there is not PHP edition in this packages group, but I can use `Helios SR2`. Now, thanks to you, I see what I've made wrong. I used Google search on `Eclipse for PHP` and it took me to [SR site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr), while I should install newest edition, from [SR2 site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr2). Thanks again!

Comment: Not, it seems, an uncommon problem.  http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.tools.pdt